# Mean of a QueueingProcess after finite time

Tags: distributions, queueing-systems

I have an M/M/1 queue. In the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QueueingProcess.html#97967390) says that one can `Slice distribution of an M/M/1 queue with inexact parameters`. This slice behaves (somehow) as a `ProbabilityDistribution` that can be given as a parameter to for example, `PDF[]`. The relevant code is:

```
Q = QueueingProcess[4.3, 5];
DiscretePlot[PDF[Q[4], x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

I want to compute the expected value of L (number of entities in the system/length of the queue) after a finite time. However, if I try to do `Mean[Q[4]]` (which seems logical *if* the slice is indeed a discrete probability distribution,) I don't get a result, but an unevaluated expression.

Below is a screenshot of a more complete example of the situation:

[image: Screenshot of slice working with PDF but not Mean]

**Question:** Is there a function or simple expression to get the expected value, or I just have to go for an infinite summation?

Comment: Use `NExpectation[]` instead: `NExpectation[k, k \[Distributed] Q[4]]`

Comment: @J.M. wow, quick. Thanks! I had tried `Expectation[]` but not the numeric version. Would you like to write that as an answer?

Comment: If you can wait a bit, sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qp = QueueingProcess[2, 5/2, 1, ∞, 0];

PDF[qp[3], k]
   PDF[QueueingProcess[2, 5/2, 1, ∞, 0][3], k]
```

Since no symbolic evaluation was happening for the PDF, `Expectation[]` (and thus, `Mean[]`) won't work either:

```
Expectation[k, k \[Distributed] qp[3]]
   Expectation[k, k \[Distributed] QueueingProcess[2, 5/2, 1, ∞, 0][3]]

Mean[qp[3]]
   Mean[QueueingProcess[2, 5/2, 1, ∞, 0][3]]
```

However, you can force *numerical* evaluation by applying `N[]`:

```
N[Mean[qp[3]], 20]
   1.7875077027096111173
```

but this is not very flexible. So, I would recommend using `NExpectation[]` directly:

```
NExpectation[k, k \[Distributed] qp[3], WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   1.7875077027096111173
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simulate:

```
q = QueueingProcess[2, 2.5, 1, Infinity, 0];
rf = RandomFunction[q, {0, 10}, 1000];
t3 = rf["SliceData", 3];
Histogram[t3, Automatic, "PDF"]
Mean[t3] // N
```

[image]